# Nginx geoip redirrects

Tags: nginx, redirect, geoip

I have web site that supports multiply languages (en, ru), when new visitor came to site it shown by default en version, but I want setup it so if visitor from Russia or Ukraine it shows ru version and when from all others countries it shows en version

Trying to set up nginx geoip but it is not working as intended. I got redirect loop or 403 forbidden
I got latest nginx on Ubuntu 18 LTS
My site in /etc/www/sitename and I got 2 folders rus and eng with it’s own index.html (or I can get back to index.html and index-rus,html in site folder)

Trying to do it in easiest way

```
geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
    default no;
    FK yes;
    FM yes;
    EH yes;
}
    if ($allowed_country = no) {
        return http://example.com/index-ru.html;
    }
```

But when allowed_country = no I got redirect loop
Thy [Nginx geoip redirect , but exclude URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071356/nginx-geoip-redirect-but-exclude-url) but got nginx error [emerg] unknown directive "redirect" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:100

How I can setup nginx geoip so it’s working properly?

Thx for answers

Comment: Which URIs should redirect to `/index-ru.html`, just `/` or are there others?

Comment: /index.html for English version and /index-ru.html for Russian or example.com/eng/index.html example.com/rus/index.html